# ListView in Django

Tags: python, django, for-loop, listview, foreign-keys

I am using Class Based views and want to display data on a webpage using ListView. Am using for loop to display many objects data. In my models, the items have a *category* field which is ForeignKey where the category is either Bags, Tshirts or Shoes. I want to display items whose Category is Shoes only. I have tried using the if condition which isnt working with the ForeignKey field. How do I filter the Category field to display Bags only?

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    createdtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

class Product(models.Model):
    mainimage = models.ImageField(upload_to='product')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category')
    previewtext = models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Preview Text')
    detailstext = models.TextField(max_length=1000, verbose_name='Description')
    price = models.FloatField()
    oldprice = models.FloatField(default=0.00)
    createddate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-createddate',]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from shopapp.models import Product

# Create your views here.
class Home(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'shopapp/home.html'
```

html file

```
<div class="container my-5">
  <h2 class="my-5">Handbags</h2>
  <div class="row">
    {% for product in object_list %}
    {% if product.category == 'Bags' %}
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
      <figure class="card card-product">
        <div class="img-wrap">
          <a href="{% url 'shopapp:productdetail' pk=product.pk %}"><img src="/media/{{ product.mainimage }}" style="width:100%; height:300px;"></a>
        </div>

        <figcaption class="info-wrap">
          <h6 class="title">{{ product.name }}</h6>
          <div class="action-wrap">
            <div class="price-wrap h5">
              <span class="price-new">${{ product.price|floatformat:2 }}</span>
              <span class="price-old"><strike>${{ product.oldprice|floatformat:2 }}</strike></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </figcaption>

      </figure>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You current template is expected to display bags only. Is it working? If it doesn't what kind of error messages do you get?

Comment: It doesnt show any error. It just displays nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code use `product.category.title` like so:

```
...
    {% if product.category.title == 'Bags' %}
...
```

You are comparing a *Category* object with the string *Bags*.

#### //edit

I also recommend filtering the data in the view, if you only need that data in the view. There is no need to fetch all the products from your database and send them to the view, just to render a portion of it.

Comment: Thank you very much. .title worked. I fetched all data and sent it to the view because I will also need to display other categories in their own sections. But I would be glad if you showed me how to filter them in the views when using Class Based views. I only know how to filter when using functions and then rendering context

Comment: Hi. There are multiple ways to filter the context. You could use the methods `get_queryset` or `get_context_data` (see [Django refs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) for more info). If it worked for you feel free to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: You can also create custom Filters and apply them to your views. This can be very powerful and generic.

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly for me but I havent reached 15 reputation to mark the answer.